# accessing parent controller from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been learning angular and found this when trying to access the parent controller 
http://jsfiddle.net/eqb23s8t/

I was expecting to access the same variable from the parent controller from inside the ng-repeat using the $parent so when one of the checkbox is pressed, all should be updated, but this is not true. Why ?.

```
 <div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
           <ul>
               <li ng-repeat="city in cities">{{city}}<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="$parent.somevar" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your jsFiddle has a ChildCtrl defined but it will have no effect because you never use it. You can delete it.

Second, as described in the ngChecked documentation, there is a difference between ngChecked and ngModel:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

If what you're expecting to happen is have all the checkboxes check/uncheck together, you probably want ngModel rather than ngChecked.

It's not clear from your question what you're actually trying to do, but here's a fork of your jsFiddle illustrating data sharing through a $parent variable:

http://jsfiddle.net/7jzyk7f6/

It just does the following:

```
<li ng-repeat="city in cities">{{city}}<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.somevar" /></li>
```

to illustrate both concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You are not bind a model for the view, which can reflect the changes. The current code just reads the model (in this case the `somevar`) state. Use `ng-model` instead of `ng-checked`. The angular will handle the rest:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="city in cities">{{city}}<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.somevar" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.cities = ["NY", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona"];
    $scope.somevar = true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqb23s8t/4/

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use `ngModel` (two-way binding) instead of `ngChecked` (one-way binding):

```
ng-model="$parent.somevar"
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q50rstvb/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also totally newbie in Angular so I can be wrong. But I see few... things in your code. First of all `ChildCtrl` is not used at all. Second, it looks like only `ng-model` directive applied two-way binding to checkboxes. Yet `ng-checked` used just to add|remove `checked` **attribute**.

And [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzeLy9nk/)

Answer (score 1):

Sir please use ng-model to refer scope of the parent.
here is what i have created demo for you [demo][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/nwg7bwLx/
```

Comment: oh sorry madam! I am from india so not familiar with these names...:-)